# Что делать, если программа не компилируется? Переопределение C++

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

Есть четыре файла: 
sfile.cpp 
button.h 
drawing_core.h 
drawing_core.cpp 
Вот их содержимое:

```
//drawing_core.h:

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

HWND   wnd;
HDC    dc;
HBRUSH brush;
HPEN   pen;

void start();
void setMainClr(int clr);
void setOutlineClr(int clr);
void setClr(int clr);
void end();
void rectangle(int x, int y, int w, int h);
void to(int x, int y);
void line(int x, int y);


//drawing_core.cpp:


#include <windows.h>
#include "drawing_core.h"

void start() {
    wnd = GetConsoleWindow();
    dc  = GetDC(wnd);
}

void setMainClr(int clr) {
    DeleteObject            (brush);
    brush = CreateSolidBrush(clr);
    SelectObject            (dc, brush);
}

void setOutlineClr(int clr) {
    DeleteObject   (pen);
    pen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, clr);
    SelectObject   (dc, pen);
}

void setClr(int clr) {
    setOutlineClr(clr);
    setMainClr   (clr);
}

void rectangle(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
    Rectangle(dc, x, y, x + w, y + h);
}

void to(int x, int y) {
    MoveToEx(dc, x, y, 0);
}

void line(int x, int y) {
    LineTo(dc, x, y);
}

void end() {
    DeleteObject(brush);
    DeleteObject(pen);
    ReleaseDC   (wnd, dc);
}



//button.h:
#include <iostream>
#include "drawing_core.h"

class button {
public:
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0; 
    int w = 100;
    int h = 50;
    int background_color = RGB(96, 96, 96);
    int foreground_color = RGB(0, 0, 0);
    std::string text = "Text";
    button(int tx, int ty, int tw, int th, std::string ttext) {
        this->x = tx;
        this->y = ty;
        this->w = tw;
        this->h = th;
        this->text = ttext;
    }
    void draw() {
        setMainClr(this->background_color);
        rectangle(this->x, this->y, this->w, this->h);
        TextOut(dc, this->x, this->y, (LPCWSTR)this->text.c_str(), 10);
    }
};

// sfile.cpp:

#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include "drawing_core.h"
#include "button.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    start();
    button b1(0, 0, 100, 50, "Hello World!");
    b1.draw();
    end();
    while (1);
    return 0;
}
```

Когда я запускаю компиляцию, вылезает ошибка:

> HBRUSH brush: переопределение 
> HDC dc: переопределение       
> HPEN pen: переопределение     
> HWND wnd: переопределение

Как убрать эту ошибку?

Comment: Устраните глобальные переменные в заголовочном файле.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В заголовочном файле `.h` глобальные переменные *предварительно* объявите с приставкой **extern** :

```
extern HWND   wnd;
extern HDC    dc;
extern HBRUSH brush;
extern HPEN   pen;
```

а в **одном** из `.cpp` файлов их место *окончательно* определите :

```
HWND   wnd;
HDC    dc;
HBRUSH brush;
HPEN   pen;
```

Comment: спасибо, всё работает